# Serverless authorizer deleted when removing separate service

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

Good afternoon all, I have been running into a weird issue with the serverless cli tool over the last week. My team and I have an authorizer that we deploy separately from our APIs. When we deploy our APIs we attach said authorizer to the API gateway. All is good and well there. But our issue comes when we go to clean up a test API. When we run `serverless remove` on an API that uses the authorizer, the authorizer itself also seems to get removed, cloudformation stack and all. I am very confused as to why removing one of our APIs seems to remove a separately deployed authorizer. I was wondering if anyone could enlighten me as to a reason this may be happening, I don't believe I saw anything in the documentation if this is an intended feature or not.

We have been doing work on feature branches for our APIs and any time someone removes their test instance from our AWS account it also removed the authorizer. I have been under the impression that running `serverless remove` in a given project only removes the resources that the project itself spun up, not other things that it interfaces with as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved, our naming we were using for both services was the same for some reason and so when one deployed it overwrote the other in cloudformation.